# Convert matplotlib data units to normalized units

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Does anyone know how to convert matplotlib data units into normalized units?

The reason that I need it is that I need to create a subplot on top of another plot.
And the default syntax:

```
plt.axes([0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3])
```

requires normalized coordinates, but I want to use the data coordinates:

For example this code:

```
  plt.plot([0,2],[2,4]);
  plt.axes([0.3,.3,0.4,.4])
```

produces this:

[image]
But I'd like to be able to define the location of the subplot using the data coordinates of it
, something like [0.7,2.5,1.7,3.5].  I've tried to fiddle with axes.transData, axes.get_transform() and the like but didn't succeed to find the right function to do the job

Comment: I don't know how to do this per se, and the `axes_grid1` toolkit can be a bit scary, but this example + some knowledge of MPL transforms might set you down the right path http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/inset_locator_demo.html.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I've forgot about axes_grid1. I've looked at it and it could be useful, but from quick glance I still don't see a way to do exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Yeah. I wish I could be more help. I've been lucky(?) enough to not need to figure out all of the transforms stuff in MPL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

inner `axes` printed at `0.5, 2.5, 1.0, 0.3` (in outer `axes` coords)

[image: inner axes printed at 0.5, 2.5, 1.0, 0.3 (in outer axes coords)]

You basically need two transformations -- one from src-coords to display, and one from display to dest-coord. From the docs there seems to be no direct way:
http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html

```
bb_data = Bbox.from_bounds(0.5, 2.5, 1.0, 0.3)
disp_coords = ax.transData.transform(bb_data)
fig_coords = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform(disp_coords)
```

`ax` and `fig` both carry transformer with them -- to display-coords!
If you call `inverted` on them, you get an transformer for the inverse direction.

Here's the full code for the above example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

plt.plot([0,2], [2,4])
fig = plt.gcf()
ax = plt.gca()

bb_data = Bbox.from_bounds(0.5, 2.5, 1.0, 0.3)
disp_coords = ax.transData.transform(bb_data)
fig_coords = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform(disp_coords)

fig.add_axes(Bbox(fig_coords))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! It would take me a while to figure this out on my own.

Comment: @sega_sai, glad to be able to help you. I have also included a link to the documentation describing transformations...

Comment: Had exactly the same question as the original poster. Spent ages grappling with inset_locator(), provided by mpl_toolkits, without much success. Eventually found this. Thanks, Theodros!