# Is there an error in scatter_piecharts.py from matplotlib examples

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use this example from the matplotlib

http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/scatter_piecharts.html

If I run this with the original data is fine but if I have small segments things start to look odd. See attached [image: figure with green sectors missing]

This happens if I change the ratios in the example to:

```
r1 = 0.6 
r2 = r1 + 0.04
```

This only seems to happen for narrow slices which have an alignment which is at about 45 degrees to the x axis. Note that I also increased the sizes by a factor of 10 to make the problem clearer.

Alternatively, can someone show me a way to get the same effect (placing pie charts on an axes at specific data co-ordinates). I looked into using mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.inset_locator but I can't work out how to make that put a plot at a point in data space, the loc argument seems to only allow you to choose a corner of the plot for it.

The long term goal is to plot this on a map.

Comment: This answer helped me solve my main issue, but doesn't answer my original question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568545/convert-matplotlib-data-units-to-normalized-units This allows me to use the pyplot pie chart in its own axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it looks  like there *is* an error in the example.  It occurs in the calculation of `s2` (and `s1`, etc.), which helps to scale the wedges so that the edges line up nicely.  The problem is that it is taking the max of both the `x` and `y` vertices, when what it really wants is the max of the *absolute value* of the vertices.

In the case where the wedge lies in the lower left quadrant, `x` and `y` are negative, which yields a max of 0, so the size is set to zero.

Changing all the "s" calculations from

```
s1 = max(max(x), max(y))
```

to

```
s1 = max(max(np.abs(x)), max(np.abs(y)))
```

should fix it.  With

```
r1 = 0.6
r2 = r1 + 0.04
```

(and bumping up the sizes a bit to see it better) it yields:
[image: corrected example image]