# How do 'normalized figure coordinates' work?

Tags: matplotlib

In matplotlib, I recently came across the term 'normalized figure coordinates', which is apparently a specification of a rectangle by four parameters.

It is evident that a rectangle can be described by four numbers, and I'm guessing these four numbers somehow describe the dimensions as well as the location of the rectangle. However, I haven't managed to find an answer as to which of these parameters specifies which value.

Additionally, I'm not sure whether this is a matplotlib-specific term or one of general meaning, as the matplotlib documentation does not cite or link any sources with respect to this term.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue, please?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/inset_locator_demo.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568545/convert-matplotlib-data-units-to-normalized-units) answer

Comment: There are several functions where normalized figure coordinates are used. Which of them are you referring to? In general possibilities are `(left, bottom, width, height)` (this is called "[bounds](https://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Bbox.from_bounds)" in matplotlib); or `(left, bottom, right, top)` (called "[extent](https://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Bbox.from_extents)"). Hopefully the documentation will make it clear which 4 tuple is expected in the respective case.

Comment: But if you can point to a place in the docs where that isn't clear, I'd be happy to clarify.

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! I was confused by [this](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html#use-with-gridspec) section where it says 'You may provide an optional rect parameter', but does not explain which parameter represents which entity. From what you said, I guess it in the "bounds" form, right?

Comment: @Sheldore your first link might not be related to the topic. Thank you for the second one. However, the question uses the coordinates of the bottom left and those of the top right corner, while the answer uses a different format, specifying the bottom left corner and the width and height of the rectangle. This is exactly what my confusion is about, which format ist used when 'normalized figure coordinates' are required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several functions where normalized figure coordinates are used.

In general possibilities are

- `(left, bottom, width, height)` (this is called "bounds" in matplotlib); or
- `(left, bottom, right, top)` (called "extent").

Hopefully the documentation will make it clear which 4 tuple is expected in the respective case.

Here you seem to be interested in the `GridSpec`'s `tight_layout` parameter `rect`. From [its documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.tight_layout)

> `rect` : tuple of 4 floats, optional
>   `(left, bottom, right, top)` rectangle in normalized figure coordinates that the whole subplots area (including labels) will fit into. Default is (0, 0, 1, 1).

Comment: Yep, there it is, right there in the documentation -- `(left, bottom, right, top)`. doh! (For anyone else like me who initially glazed over "extraneous" info on first and second readings of the docs.)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, the term normalization is not matplotlib-specific you can get a very short intro from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)).

As for Matplotlib: you can have different coordinate systems relative to different objects (e.g. the axis, the figure).
Each of these systems is normalized, in the sense that the 4 corners of the chosen reference object will always have the following coordinates:

```
(0,1) Top left corner 
(1,1) Top right corner 
(1,0) Bottom right corner 
(0,0) Bottom left corner
```

Where the first element of each pair refers to `x-axis` and the second element refers to the `y-axis`.

This makes, among other things, annotation or placements of artist objects easier as you can specify the position of the element you wish to add using any of the available coordinate systems.
All you need to do is select an appropriate coordinate system by passing a transformation object to the transform parameter.

Some example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([5.], [2.], 'o')

circle=plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.1, color="g",transform=ax.transAxes) #bottom (y=0) left (x=0) green circle of radius 0.1 (expressed in coord system)
ax.add_artist(circle)

ax.annotate('I am the top (y=1.0) right (x=1.0) Figure corner',
            xy=(1, 1), xycoords=fig.transFigure,
            xytext=(0.2, 0.2), textcoords='offset points',
            )

plt.text(  # position text relative to data
    5., 2., 'I am the (5,2) data point',  # x, y, text,
    ha='center', va='bottom',   # text alignment
    transform=ax.transData      # coordinate system transformation
)
plt.text(  # position text relative to Axes
    1.0, 0.0, 'I am the bottom (y=0.0) right (x=1.0) axis corner',
    ha='right', va='bottom',
    transform=ax.transAxes
)
plt.text(  # position text relative to Figure
    0.0, 1.0, 'I am the top (y=1.0) left (x=0.0) figure corner',
    ha='left', va='top',
    transform=fig.transFigure
)


plt.show()
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative example! This makes things much clearer for me. So do you think the 4 numbers like [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html#use-with-gridspec) (if you scroll down a little bit, you'll see a parameter `rect` with `rect=[0, 0, .5, 1]`) are 
* x of bottom left corner,
* y of bottom left corner,
* x of top right corner,
* y of top right corner?
I understand the normalization part now, I just haven't found any documentation about the semantics of this parameter.

Comment: Additionally, in your plot, the figure is much wider than the axes. How did you accomplish that? This is what I initially wanted to do - placing text to the left of the axes and making the figure bigger than the axes for this purpose.

Comment: @TobiasFeil Yes, the coordinates are `rect=[x, y, x*, y*]` as you said they represent:  `x` bottom left corner, `y` bottom left corner, `x*` top right corner, `y*` top right corner. Following the example you linked you can play around with the values and see by yourself how the subplot areas varies. Adding the very long text in the figure corners automatically stretched the figure size.

Comment: An important (and in the scope of this question confusing) detail in this answer is that the code is run in IPython/Juypter using the IPython `inline` backend. This will produce a saved png version of the figure with the `savefig`'s `bbox_inches="tight"` parameter set. What it does is to expand (or crop) the figure to accomodate all content; but this leads to the figure coordinates loosing their meaning for the png file. A text that is outside the figure (with figure coordinates > 1) is still perfectly visible. Understand that the figure size is not stretched, but the png image size is.